# book related query

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, probability, statistics, reference-request

I have been solving a lot of problems in algebra, calculus, probability and statistics. But have never encountered problems that consist of every mathematical field mentioned above (at max two concepts). I wanted to know a book that amalgamates all these concepts together in a comprehensive and lucid manner with challenging questions after every sub concept.

Comment: Get a book filled with JEE Main and JEE Advanced Math Questions. I suggest McGraw & Hill JEE Main Mathematics.